# Compress multiple videos at once on a Mac

Tags: video, compression, automation

I want to reduce the file size of a bunch of videos at once on my Mac.

Would you know any free tool that does that or any way to automate a loop in Automator to pilot Handbrake to loop on a given folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Handbrake can queue](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/advanced/queue.html) up a batch of files.

FFmpeg is free and works on a mac, but you'd have to run it from Terminal.
You can install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for Mac.

Once Homebrew is installed, go to Terminal and type

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Then you should be able to change directory to wherever your files are by typing something like:

```
cd /Users/my.username/Movies
```

where my.username would be your username on that mac, and Movies would be whatever directory the files were in

Then you can convert them by typing something like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.webm
```

Where input.mp4 is your source file, and output.webm is your output file.

To convert all the mp4 files in that directory you would enter

```
ffmpeg -i *.mp4 output.webm
```

[More info on selecting different codecs](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/ffmpeg-convert-media-file-formats) etc.